# how to add empty field to activeDropDownList yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

i have a drop down list using ArrayHelper::map
as below code:

```html
<?= Html::activeDropDownList($model2, 'expert_id',
      ArrayHelper::map(Experts::find()->all(), 'username', 'username')) ?>
```

that works correctly but i want to add empty fields or other favorite fields ...
how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use array merge

```
 <?= Html::activeDropDownList($model2, 'expert_id',
  array_merge(array('val1'=>'val1'), ArrayHelper::map(Experts::find()->all(), 'username', 'username'))) ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

cleaner: (if you just want to add empty fields)

```
<?= Html::activeDropDownList($model2, 'expert_id',
   ArrayHelper::map(Experts::find()->all(), 'username', 'username')), array('placeholder'=>'') ?>
```